# Always force Referenced DLL to update?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I'm working on a solution that produces some DLLs.  Let's say Project A produces A.dll.  Project B uses A.dll to perform some functions.

When Project B is ran, it checks if A.dll exists in the output directory, and if it doesn't, it copies A.dll from the HintPath (as I understand it).  But if A.dll is already in the output directory, it doesn't copy over.

So if Project A has changes and a new A.dll is produced, Project B won't get the new A.dll until the copy in the output directory is deleted.  Therefore, if you run Project B, it will be using old code.

Is there a way to force the DLLs to always get copied?  Maybe delete the copies in the output directory before Project B is built?

It would be so easy to use `ProjectReference` but it's unsupported by another build system we use.

Comment: You can establish project dependencies between different projects in visual studio, have you tried that? Create the solution, add those projects and then determine the project dependencies.

Comment: What other build system do you use?  If references aren't supported, when they're specifically designed for this, you really need to tell us what it is so we can try to avoid any other unsupported features.

Answer (score 3):

One way to resolve this issue is in Project A to make a Post-Build event. You can tell it to copy(or replace) the A.dll to a certain directory every time in Project A is built. Something like this:

```
copy /Y "$(TargetDir)$(ProjectName).dll" "C:\SomePath"
```